# SED to parse apache logs between timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to parse a log and get the lines between timestamp.Tried sed approach like below but facing issue with regex

Log pattern:

```
IP - - [20/Apr/2018:14:25:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 3936 "-" "
IP - - [20/Apr/2018:14:44:08 +0000]
----------------------------------

IP- - [20/Apr/2018:20:43:46 +0000]
```

I need to get the lines between `14:25` and `20:43` for 20th april as the log contains other dates also.

Tried this:

```
sed -n '/\[14:25/,/\[20:43/p' *-https_access.log.1
```

but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you want logs for 20th April, I'd suggest something like :

```
$ sed -n '/20\/Apr\/2018:14:25/,/20\/Apr\/2018:20:43/p' *-https_access.log.1
```

This is very less likely to conflict with false matches in case "20:43" occurs elsewhere.

Comment: This will fail if the strings `20/Apr/2018:14:25` or `20/Apr/2018:20:43` are not in the log-file

Comment: For me the command (not exact but structure is the same) from this answer works incorrectly - it parses logs till the end of the file, not till the second date. What works for me is this variant: `sed -n '/^17.01.24 13:00/, $p' /home/apache-tomcat*/logs/catalina.out | sed -n '1, /^17.01.24 14:30/p'`

Answer (score 0):

To print lines between `match1` and `match2` with sed or awk you can do:

```
sed -n '/match1/,/match2/p' inputfile
awk '/match1/,/match2/' inputfile
```

in your example `match1` is `20/Apr/2018:14:25` and `match2` is `20/Apr/2018:20:43`. So any of these commands should work for you:

```
sed -n '/20\/Apr\/2018:14:25/,/20\/Apr\/2018:20:43/p' inputfile
awk '/20\/Apr\/2018:14:25/,/20\/Apr\/2018:20:43/' inputfile
```

or use `|` as a sed's delimiter to prevent escaping slash:

```
sed -n '\|20/Apr/2018:14:25|,\|20/Apr/2018:20:43|p' inputfile
```

Comment: works only IF the date and hour are in the log. it's the case here but you should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

sed is not appropriate because it's hard to compare element (like day and hour).

with awk (self commented):

```
awk -F '[ []' '
  {
  # separt date and hour then rebuild the fields
  sub(/:/, " ", $5);$0=$0""
  }

  # print if it s the day and between the 2 hour (string compare works in this case)
  $5 ~ /20.Apr.2018/ && $6 >= "04:25" &&  $7 < "20:44"
  ' YourFile
```

more generaly, we can use variable to give date and hour as paramter to the awk (not the purpose here)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `awk` for this. What you need to do is convert your time-stamps to a unix-time and then do the comparisons. In `awk` you can do this using `mktime()`

> **`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`:** Turn datespec into a timestamp in the same form as is returned by `systime()`. It is similar to the
>   function of the same name in ISO C. The argument, datespec, is a
>   string of the form `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]`. The string consists of
>   six or seven numbers representing, respectively, the full year
>   including century, the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month from 1
>   to 31, the hour of the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0 to 59, the
>   second from 0 to 60,55 and an optional daylight-savings flag.

In order to convert your time-format of the form `20/Apr/2018:14:25:37 +0000` into `2018 04 20 14 25 37 +0000`

```
awk -v tstart="20/Apr/2018:14:25:00" -v tend = "20/Apr/2018:20:43:00" \
     'function tounix(str) {
        split(str,a,"/|:| ")
        return mktime(a[3]" "month[a[2]]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6])
     }
     BEGIN{
       month["Jan"]="01";month["Feb"]="02";month["Mar"]="03"
       month["Apr"]="04";month["May"]="05";month["Jun"]="06"
       month["Jul"]="07";month["Aug"]="08";month["Sep"]="09"
       month["Oct"]="10";month["Nov"]="11";month["Dec"]="12"
       FS="\\[|\\]"
       t1=tounix(tstart)
       t2=tounix(tend)
     }
     { t=tounix($2) }
     (t1<=t && t<=t)' <file>
```

This method is robust as it will do true time comparisons which are independent of leap years, day/month/year-cross-overs, ... In contrast to other solutions provided, this method also does not require the existence of the date `tstart` and `tend` in the `file`

Comment: Can you make it as one liner and remake it for dates format `20.04.18`?